# $L^p$ norm of $g:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: functional-analysis, terminology, normed-spaces, lp-spaces

If I understand correctly, the $L^p$ norm of $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is $$\|f\|_p=\left(\int_{-\infty}^\infty |f(x)|^pdx\right)^{1/p}$$

But is the $L^p$ norm of $g:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^n$ defined?

Is it this? 
$$\left(\int_{-\infty}^\infty \|g(x)\|_pdx\right)^{1/p}$$
Is there a name for this norm? 
$$\left(\int_{-\infty}^\infty \|g(x)\|_2^{p}dx\right)^{1/p}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The space of all measurable functions $g: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R^{n}$ with $\int \|g\|_2^{p}<\infty$ is denoted by $L^{p} (\mathbb R, \mathbb R^{n})$. More generally we can talk about $L^{p} (\mathbb R , X)$ for any normed linear space $X$.

However $(\int\|g\|_p)^{1/p}$ is not a norm.

Comment: Can the $L^p(\mathbb{R},X)$ norm of $f$ be denoted by $||f||_{L^p}$ or must it be denoted by $||f||_{L^p(\mathbb{R},X)}$?

Comment: It is better to use the second notation. But if the range $X$ is understood you can use the first notation.